# Fixing an XLSM in which macros can run but not perform sheet actions

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have a weird situation in which a certain user (Windows 10 with Office 2016, no third party protection) can open my XLSM file and run its macros (after enabling macros for that file), but the macros (various ones, unrelated to each other) get stuck as soon as they try to perform an action.

Actions can be anything from expanding/collapsing pivot tables to refreshing connections. So, for example, there are **no** errors for purely programming non sheet commands like *some_number=50* or *some_value=true*. But *range("a1").value="test"* will probably trigger an error.

The same file works perfectly fine for myself and other users

Weirder still, other very similar macros work for that user with other files of mine.

But weirdest of all, sometimes it **does** work fine for that user! Then a second later it doesn't.

Any idea what causes this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code all I can do is offer suggestions;

First try to open the file with a predecessor :

```
Sub lkjhgf()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="problem.xlsm"
End Sub
```

This will shutoff Events to see if this is causing the problem

The second is to insure that every instance of `On Error` code yields a MsgBox to display the problem.